# Conditionally publish gradle artifacts

Tags: gradle, artifactory, publishing

Currently when someone checks in code Jenkins picks this up builds, analyses, etc and then publishes the artifact to Artifactory (currently using the Jenkins Artifactory plugin but happy to move to pure gradle).

Alot of that code is tests (unit and automated acceptance tests) so it seems wasteful to build and deploy a new artifact to artifactory, which in turn requires deploying and running the automated tests when a commit only touches test code.

How can I skip the publish step if no application code has changed?

Comment: There is no easy way to accomplish that, but perhaps there is a different solution. Is it really the publishing step that triggers deploying and running the automated tests? And why would you not want to rerun tests if (only) test code changed? Please explain your build pipeline in more detail.

Comment: besides @PeterNiederwieser's remark, also note that artifactory will not duplicate your (business code) jar if it's identical to a previous deploy. So, wrt artifactory, I would not bother about that "seemingly wasteful" deployment.. search for "checksum" on https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin

Comment: It's not that I don't want to re-run the tests - I definately do, I just don't want to recompile the artifacts and publish those to Artifactory.  Each build is treated as a new version (named in this format: "base_name.major.minor.bugfix.build.ear") so even if no changes a new copy is loaded with a new version number.